# Making popper or div height '100%' in React and material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have jsx like this.

```
  <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} style={{opacity:'0.5',width:'100%',size:'100%'}}>
  <div style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>The content of the Popper.</div>
  </Popper>
  <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
    Toggle Popper
  </button>
```

With this, `Popper` becomes width 100% but not height 100%

I googled around and found I need to make `html` and `body` 100%

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

However I use `Material-UI` with `Reactjs`

So, I am not sure where should I put this code.

These are my code

my `jsx`

```
 return (
    <div style={{backgroundColor:"#212325"}}>
      <Header
        brand="my brand"
        rightLinks={<HeaderLinks />}
        fixed
        color="transparent"
        changeColorOnScroll={{
          height: 50,
          color: "white"
        }}
        {...rest}
      />
     
      <Container maxWidth="md">
          <Grid container style={{paddingTop:"100px"}}>

      
            <Box mt={2} mb={2}>
              <ParamBoard></ParamBoard>
              </Box>
          </Grid>

          <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} style={{opacity:'0.5',width:'100%',size:'900px'}}>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>The content of the Popper.</div>
      </Popper>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} >
              <ListMix></ListMix>
          </Grid>
      </Container>
      <Footer />
    
    </div>
  );
```

my `style`

```
import { container } from "assets/jss/material-kit-react.js";

const componentsStyle = {
  root:{
    flexGrow: 0,

  },
  container,
  brand: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    textAlign: "left"
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: "4.2rem",
    fontWeight: "600",
    display: "inline-block",
    position: "relative"
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: "1.313rem",
    maxWidth: "500px",
    margin: "10px 0 0"
  },
  main: {
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: "3"
  },
  mainRaised: {
    margin: "-60px 30px 0px",
    borderRadius: "6px",
    boxShadow:
      "0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
  },
  link: {
    textDecoration: "none"
  },
  textCenter: {
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  myRadioLabel:{
    fontSize: "1.0rem"
  },

};

export default componentsStyle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you need to give you root component a height of 100% aswel so in you `.jsx` file the line:

```
 <div style={{backgroundColor:"#212325"}}>
```

will need to be...

```
 <div style={{backgroundColor:"#212325", height: '100%'}}>
```